# How do get loop results into a vector or matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

Here is the thing:
I have while loop nested in a for loop.
I can get the results of each iteration as a result for the variable flp. But now i want all these results stored in a vector with same number of rows as another variable called eci. I'm aware that i have to preallocate the vector. But how do i move on from here?
Tank you!

Here is the code i've done so far:

```
for eci=0:0.0002:ecu
    fl=0;
    fcc=fc0*(2.254*sqrt(1+7.94*fl/fc0)-2*fl/fc0-1.254);
    ecc=ec0*(1+5*(fcc/fc0-1));
    r=Ec/(Ec-fcc/ecc);
    x=eci/ecc;
    fc=fcc*x*r/(r-1+x^r);
    el=(Ec*eci-fc)/(2*beta*fc);
    flp=ke*kr*2*nf*tf*Ef*1000*el/B;
    while abs(fl-flp)>0.0001
        fl=flp;
        fcc=fc0*(2.254*sqrt(1+7.94*fl/fc0)-2*fl/fc0-1.254);
        ecc=ec0*(1+5*(fcc/fc0-1));
        r=Ec/(Ec-fcc/ecc);
        x=eci/ecc;
        fc=fcc*x*r/(r-1+x^r);
        el=(Ec*eci-fc)/(2*beta*fc);
        flp=ke*kr*2*nf*tf*Ef*1000*el/B
    end
end

eci=[0:0.0002:ecu]';
m=size(eci);
m(:,2)=[];
mat_result=zeros(m,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite stimple, start with an empty vector, for example:

```
results = zeros(length(0:0.0002:ecu),1);
```

Then just start counting with `t=t+1` somewhere in the loop (initialize properly ofcourse) and store the restult:

```
results(t) = myResult
```